Force balance condition at the interface of contact between a deformable and a rigid body

Consider a structure comprising an elastic deformable body (in pink) attached to a rigid body (in yellow) at the right side ( $\Gamma_c$ interface) and fixed at the left side.
Assume a force $F$ is applied to the rigid body at an angle $\beta$, as shown in the diagram. Subsequently, the deformable body undergoes deformation.
What is the condition for force balance at the bilateral contact interface?
I propose that it could be expressed as:
$$\int_{\Gamma_c} \boldsymbol{\sigma}~\textbf{n}~~ d\Gamma_c = \boldsymbol{F}$$
where $F_x = - F cos(\beta)$ and $F_z = - F sin(\beta)$, $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is the stress tensor of the deformable body, and $\textbf{n}$ is the normal vector at the interface.
Is this equation correct?
